# how to get last index of array ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

how to get array last index + 1 using ng-repeat directive ?? 
dynamic  Profile.addresses[2].site_name

```html
<tr ng-repeat="lines in array">
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault" ng-model=' Profile.addresses[2].site_name ' name='site_name'>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault" ng-model=' Profile.addresses[2].street_address ' name='street_address'>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault" ng-model=' Profile.addresses[2].city ' name='city'>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault" ng-model=' Profile.addresses[2].state ' name='state'>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault" ng-model=' Profile.addresses[2].country ' name='country'>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault" ng-model=' Profile.addresses[2].zip_code ' name='zip_code'>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault" ng-model=' Profile.addresses[2].phone_number ' name='phone_number'>
  </td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 6):

You'll be looking for **$last**.

In the [ngRepeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) documentation there are a number of special properties such as $index, $first, and $last is one of them.

Comment: Profile.addresses {{$last}}.site_name   ??  like this ?

Comment: @AdeelKhan - Like this `Profile.addresses[$last].site_name`

Comment: how to get last index +1 value ?   ng-model=' Profile.addresses [$last + 1].site_name  like this not working

Comment: @tymeJV  i want lastindex + 1 number, like last index 2 i want 3

Comment: Are you trolling us? The last index + 1 does not exist and is outside of the array bounds! If you are saying you just want the number of the last index + 1, you can add 1 to it yourself.